# mksysb backup failure: "0042-154 c_stat : the file or directory ... does not exist"

Tags: backup, aix

I have an environment with more than 40 AIX. The nim mksysb backup feature was running just fine for all of them, but for 3-4 weeks one particular server started to fail the mksysb with the following message:

"
Creating information file (/image.data) for rootvg.

Creating list of files to back up

.
Backing up 80524 files..................

0512-005 savevg: Backup Completed.

```
    The backup command completed with errors.

    The messages displayed on Standard Error contained additional
    information.
```

0042-001 nim: processing error encountered on "master":

0042-001 m_mkbosi: processing error encountered on "leda":

0042-001 m_mkbosi: processing error encountered on "master":

0042-154 c_stat: the file or directory "/nim/mksysb/lpars/mksysb_leda" does not exist

"

Information:

- Nim Client AIX: 6.1TL07SP06
- Nim Server AIX: 6.1TL09SP04
- fsize limit in both client and NIM server is 'unlimited'
- Filesystems are JFS2
- Nim client is the active node of a cluster and the sister node works fine.
- If I create the mksysb on the node manually it works.
- I refreshed NFS cache on NIM server
- Nothing was changed on the client before the problem started.

Googling around I found some people with the same problem, but most of them solved it setting the fsize limit to -1, which doesn't apply to my case.

Anyone has any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in finding the problem.
Although the NIM command that generates the mksysb which is triggered from the Master and uses NFS filesystem as repository, the commands was failing because of "full" /tmp of the NIM client, even though /tmp had more than 700MB free space. I increased the filesystem size of /tmp so I would have more than 1GB. This solved my problem.